# How to get combined output in lambda function using mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aws-lambda, pymongo

I have two collection 1) ram 2) details. find the below pic for your reference.[RAM collection details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRE2u.jpg)

[details collection details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7UMB.jpg)

In the lambda function, when i passed the rank in event, we will get the output the related rank. but i need more details in the same output.

Eg: when i passed the rank event 10002, then we will get the rank 10002 relevant data display. but i need along with user details like ramesh, suresh
details from details collection.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=1))

posts = db.user_posts

rankid = event['rank']

disposts = list(posts.find({"rank" : rankid}))
posts = json.dumps(disposts, default=json_util.default)
return json.loads(posts)
```

In this above code, i will get only one collection data. I need both collections data on same lambda function.

My expected output like this below.

```
rank : 10002,
details: 
      0 : Object
        username : "ramesh",
        des : "developer",
        edu : "b.tech",
        age : 25
      1 : Object
        username : "suresh",
        des : "admin",
        edu : "mba",
        age : 27
```

not exactly,  i need the output similar.

Can you please help me out with the proper code.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query :

```
 db.getCollection('ram').aggregate([{ $match: { rank: '10002' } }, { $unwind: '$details' }, {
    $lookup:
    {
        from: "details",
        let: { userName: '$details.username' },
        pipeline: [
            {
                $match:
                {
                    $expr:
                    {
                        $eq: ['$$userName', '$username']
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        as: "user_details"
    }
}, { $addFields: { 'user_details.des': '$details.des' } }, { $group: { _id: '$rank', details: { "$push": { $arrayElemAt: ["$user_details", 0] } } } }, { $project: { rank: '$_id', _id: 0, details: 1 } }])
```

Maybe you need to consider storing **des** field of **RAM** collection in **details** collection, that way you'll only have **username** mapped to **username** field in details collection, it would be easy that way.

Comment: HI bro, thanks for your valuable information. I tried some other joins based on the above solutions but i get an empty out. i have explain clearly with expected output. please find the below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57397863/how-to-combined-two-output-in-lambda-function-using-mongodb   Can you please help out with the changes bro. thanks you

Comment: @RameshReddy : Can you give me collection data as text, giving me pics is like I need to input those things in DB each one, that's a long job..!!

Comment: bro if you have time, can you please give me the solution for this query            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57808466/is-it-possible-to-use-group-aggregation-in-invoke-lamda-function

Comment: @RameshReddy : that should be possible within code(saying with general programming knowledge - but not sure how difficult it is with python), but I'm very beginner in python, So I can't help on that !

Comment: bro if you have time, can you please help with answer for the below query  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57996739/how-to-write-matched-condition-for-array-values

Comment: Hi Bro, if you don't mine, can you please give the solutions for the below query. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59440712/multiple-images-upload-in-s3-bucket-using-nodejs-in-aws-lambda