# How to combined two output in lambda function using mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aws-lambda, pymongo

I have two collection 1) profile ,2) posts find the below pic for your reference. [user_prfoile collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z63Ga.jpg)

[user_posts collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIdpc.png)

In the lambda function, when i passed the userid, then we will get the userid revlevant data display. but i need user details in feelings array.

I tried with the below code, but i get the empty output

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=1))


Userid = event['userid']
uid = ObjectId(Userid)

dispost = list( db.user_posts.aggregate([{ "$match" : { "userid" : uid } }, 
{ "$unwind" : "$user_profile" },
{"$lookup":
    {
        "from" : 'user_profile',
        "localField" : 'feelings.userid',
        "foreignField" : '_id',
        "as" : 'user_details'
    }
},  
{ "$addFields" : { "user_details.feelings.username" : "$user_profile.username", "user_details.feelings.photo" : "$user_profile.photo"}},
{ "$group" :  { 
            "_id" : "$_id", 
            "user_profile" : { 
                "$push" : { 
                        "$arrayElemAt" :  ["$user_details", 0]
}}}}, 
{ "$project" : { "_id" : "$_id", "userid" : 1, "type" : 1, "feelings" : 1 }}
]))
disair = json.dumps(dispost, default=json_util.default)
return json.loads(disair)
```

I get an empty output.

I need output like this below.

```
_id :
userid : 
type : 
location :
feelings : 
   [ {userid : objectid(""),
     username : "nipun",
     photo : " "},
     {userid : objectid(""),
     username : "ramesh",
     photo : " "}
   ]
```

in feelings array , i need user details from user_profile collection based on userid in feelings array.

Comment: you've to do $unwind on feelings array of user_posts. Please provide documents in text format rather than images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there are couple of issues with that aggregation query, keeping most of it as is, I've modified it to work, as of now please try this and make any changes needed :

```
db.getCollection('user_posts').aggregate([{ "$match": { "userid": uid } },
{ "$unwind": "$feelings" },
{
    "$lookup":
    {
        "from": 'user_profile',
        "localField": 'feelings.userid',
        "foreignField": '_id',
        "as": 'feelings'
    }
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id", userPost: { "$first": "$$CURRENT" }, "feelings": {
            "$push": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$feelings", 0] }
        }
    }
}, { "$project": { userid: '$userPost.userid', type: '$userPost.type', "feelings": 1 } }
])
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro. it's working fine. I have one small query bro, In feeling array i need username and photo only from user_profile collection. How can i remove other columns.

Comment: @RameshReddy : Quick thing is to do "feelings.username": 1, "feelings.photo": 1 in $project, or if you really think there are a lot of fields to be added then use $addFields, while on mapping if possible only map to necessary fields !!

Comment: bro above solutions working , i have one more last query. In user_post, i have userid right. i need username, photo based on userid. I tried one more join but it is not working.

Comment: @RameshReddy : that’s what this query does, do you see any issue in it ?

Comment: no bro, my query is we have two userid in document of user_posts collection. previously we are working on feelings userid. now i need outside userid user details along with feelings userid user details.

Comment: @RameshReddy : For two lookups, we can try to achieve from almost same query but it would have redundant data rather try using $facet and merge all stages output from facet in your code !! Try for it if not I can give it a try.

Comment: Bro is it possible write multiple $lookup's  using $group aggregation. In the same user_posts collection, I need two more joins similar to feelings array. so is it possible  or any other solution bro

Comment: @RameshReddy : you need to check this : (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html)

Comment: Bro, I tried many solutions but i didn't get correct output. can please help me the solution find the below link new query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57496378/how-to-do-multiple-joins-between-two-collection-in-mongodb-using-lambda-function

Comment: @RameshReddy : Ok

Comment: Bro any solution? for this below query  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57496378/how-to-do-multiple-joins-between-two-collection-in-mongodb-using-lambda-function

Comment: bro I have one small query on the above solution. we have two more fields in user_posts collections in feelings array. feelings : [ "userid" , "ObjectId("  "), "feel" : "happy, "text" : "hello" ], then how to display userid, feel, text along with the matched username and photo

Comment: @RameshReddy : Can you ask a new question with needed data & required o/p.

Comment: Bro I have one query about the lambda functions. Can you please help with the solution. Please find the new query link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57696138/is-it-possible-to-combine-three-lambda-functions-in-one-lambda-function